# Poor performance using GPU with tensorflow?

Tags: keras, gpu, nvidia, tensorflow

I'm trying to train an LSTM network on a corpus of text(~7M), however it's taking extremely long per epoch even though it's on an Nvidia Tesla p100.

My model structure is 2 LSTM layers with 256 neurons each, interspersed by Dropout and a final fully connected layer. I am splitting it into 64 char chunk sentences.

Any reason for this insanely slow performance? It's almost 7.5 hours per epoch! Could it be due to the CPU computation warnings? I didn't think this would cause issues with GPU computations.

[image]

Comment: Check with `nvidia-smi` how much of the GPU is being used, so that you know if this is the actual performance bottleneck.

Comment: try cntk backend much faster than tf for lstms

https://github.com/szilard/benchm-dl/blob/master/keras_backend.md

Comment: @grovina nvidia-smi doesn't seem to be showing any bottleneck

Comment: Then it could be your CPU or the data transfer itself (from memory to GPU). Check `htop` for CPU usage, and try increasing batch size to see if you can use more GPU and speed things up.